# How to remove the chat value in array tab in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rsuite

```
tabs: [ '/home', '/about', '/chat' ];

<ResponsiveNav ppearance="subtle" justified
                  removable
                  moreText={<Icon icon="more" />}
                  moreProps={{ noCaret: true }}
                  activeKey={activePage['link']}
                  onSelect={onSelectTab}
                  onItemRemove={eventKey => {
                    console.log(eventKey)
                  }}>
                  {tabs.map(tab => {
                    const menu = menus.find(a => a.link === tab);
                    return <ResponsiveNav.Item key={menu ?.key} eventKey={tab}> {menu ?.label}</ResponsiveNav.Item>
                  })}
                </ResponsiveNav>
```

How to remove the value `'/chat'` from the tabs.
What I tried is I added this on the `onItemRemove`

```
  const tabList = [...tabs]
                  tabList.splice(
                    tabList.map(item => item).indexOf(eventKey),
                    1
                  );

                  tabs.push(...tabList)

                  router.push(tabList[0] ? tabList[0] : '/')
```

But It doesn't work. Every time I click it keep pushing a value.

Comment: is `/chat` last option in array every time ?

Comment: @Codenewbie no, it can be randomized. like ```['/chat', '/home', '/about']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const sample = ['/home', '/about', '/chat']
const index = sample.indexOf('/chat') // get index here

sample.splice(index,1) // delete one element at (index)
console.log(sample)
```